# how to get download URL after image insertion into firebase.storage

Tags: xamarin.android, firebase-storage

I am able to insert the image to firebase.storage but the download link I get is not the same download link attached to the image when it is uploaded.

```
public void UploadImage()
{
    if (filePath != null)
        progressBar.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    var images = storageRef.Child("profilePicture");
    images.PutFile(filePath);    
}

void IOnSuccessListener.OnSuccess(Java.Lang.Object result)
{
    var snapShot = (UploadTask.TaskSnapshot)result;
    var downloadURL = snapShot.DownloadUrl.Scheme
        + ":" + snapShot.DownloadUrl.SchemeSpecificPart;
}

UserData newUser = new UserData();
newUser.UserId = UserId;
newUser.Email = UserEmail;
newUser.FirstName = first.Text;
newUser.LastName = last.Text;
newUser.MobileNumber = phone.Text;
newUser.Userprofile = storageRef.DownloadUrl;
```

Comment: After image upload you need to  call storageRef.getDownloadUrl() method to download url of the image. I have code in native Android & IOS but not in xamarin, If you say I can share it with you.

Comment: ok can you share it

Answer (score 1):

I can share native Android & IOS code to get URL from Firebase uploaded image/file, may be you could get some help from that for Xamarin.

Android:

```
Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
    @Override
    public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
            throw task.getException();
        }

        // Continue with the task to get the download URL
        return fileRef.getDownloadUrl();
    }
}).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
            String stringUrl = downloadUri.toString(); // Image url


        } else {
            // Handle failures
            Log.e("oops","problem occurred");
        }
    }
});
```

IOS:

```
fileRef.downloadURL { (url, error) in
  guard let downloadURL = url else {
      // Uh-oh, an error occurred!
      print("Uh-oh, an error occurred! in url downloading")

      return
  }
  print("downloadurl: \(downloadURL.absoluteString)");

}
```

Comment: Its a code snippet to get only uploaded file url, But If you need I can share complete functions to upload image & then get image url.

Comment: I have, no error in the code but its still not working